# Ubuntu 16.04 make error

Tags: software-installation, make

I try to install an wlan adaper driver on my ubuntu 16.04. Is use these cmd's:

```
git clone https://github.com/jurobystricky/Netgear-A6210
cd Netgear-A6210
make
sudo make install
```

but when I do "make" it stops after a while with the message:

Clock skew detected. Your build may be uncomplete.

Does anyone know what I can do about that?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824500/compiling-c-on-remote-linux-machine-clock-skew-detected-warning " if you are building from scratch (not doing an incremental build) you can likely ignore this warning without consequence."

Answer (score 1):

The error message means that when `make` tried to make a dependent file it found that the newly made file is still older than the source.

It may be the case that your clock is actually skewed, i.e., very wrong. Check that your clock is reasonably correct. Or it may be the case that the timestamps of your files are wrong, for example one of the files may have a timestamp in the future. Check that all the files have plausible timestamps.